# Vertical Alignment in Survey/Table

Tags: tables, formatting

I'd like to mimic the survey format below in Latex. I wondered if someone could perhaps provide a short example in how to ensure that text within each box is vertically aligned to match this style, please?

Would be appreciated.

Following Zarko's feedback, so far I have tried:
[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \scriptsize 
    \vspace{1em}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
    \captionsetup[figure]{skip=20pt}
    \caption{EQ-5D-3L Instrument:}
    \vspace*{1mm}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} P{2.0cm}  P{2.5cm} P{7.5cm}} 
    \midrule 
    \midrule
    Dimension & Level & Description\\
    \midrule 
    \midrule  
    \\ Mobility & 1 & I have no problem in walking about
    \\ &       2 & I have some problems in walking about
    \\ & 3 & I am confined to bed
    \\
        \midrule 
        \midrule 
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What you try so far? this seems that it to be quite elementary/simple  table.

Comment: Hi Zarko. I'll update with my code. But really, my goal is to keep the third column aligned.

Comment: Does it have to be a table? Would you be ok with a pair of nested lists?

Comment: Yeah, Mico. Thanks for your feedback. Preferably a table so I can include headings. I've updated the image accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document with your table. So we not get any information about your document,
  nor definitions of your table columns specification.
- Code fragment contain only first three table rows,
- Your code, if I inserted it to some small document and instead of ˙P`columns (which are undefined) use standard`p`, works fine, so what is the problem?
- Below is an example of MWE, which for table use `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{EQ-5D-3L Instrument:}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l c X[l] @{}},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!30}
             }
    \toprule
Dimension & Level & Description\\
    \midrule
Mobility    & 1 & I have no problem in walking about                        \\ 
            & 2 & I have some problems in walking about                     \\ 
            & 3 & I am confined to bed                                      \\
    \addlinespace
Self-care (SC)
            & 1 & I have no problem with self-care                          \\
            & 2 & I have some problems with washing and dressing myself     \\
            & 3 & I am unable to bed wash and dress myself                  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

- Please, tell us, what actually is your problem?

Comment: Hi Zarko. Thanks for your time. Greatly appreciated. My core problem was really just ensuring that the third column was vertically aligned to the left.